# Two different ways to write C(A)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

let $\mathrm A \in \Bbb R^{m\times n}$ I know that the three fundamental subspaces are:

$\mathrm \ker(\mathrm A) = \{ x \in \Bbb R^n : \mathrm Ax = 0 \} = \{x\in \Bbb R^n : \langle \mathrm{row_iA,x}\rangle = 0, \space i = 1,...,n\}$

$\mathrm R (\mathrm A ) =\mathrm {gen} [ \mathrm {row_1A,...,row_nA}] = \{x \in \Bbb R^n : \mathrm Ax = b, \space \mathrm{consistent}\}$

$\mathrm C(\mathrm A)= \mathrm{gen}[\mathrm{column_1A,...,column_nA}] = \color{blue}{\{...\}}$

So, a few days ago, I heard that $\mathrm{C(A)}$ can be written as a set that contains the generator of the constraint equations of the null rows of $\mathrm A$

This is, for example:

Let $\mathrm A = \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 1 & 0  \\
     2 & 1 & 1  \\
     1 & -1 & 2   
     \end{pmatrix}$
find $\mathrm X$ such that $\mathrm{C(A)=\ker(X)}$

The augmented matrix of $\mathrm A$, 
$\left[
   \begin{array}{c|c}
     \mathrm A& \mathrm b
    \end{array}
  \right]
= \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
       1 & 1 & 0 & b_1 \\
       2 & 1 & 1  &b_2\\
       1 & -1 & 2 &b_3   
    \end{array}
   \right]$

Then, row-reducing the matrix by the Gauss-Jordan method I found

$\left[
   \begin{array}{c|c}
     \mathrm A& \mathrm b
    \end{array}
  \right]_R
= \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
       1 & 0 & 1  & \color{red}{-b_1+b_2} \\
       0 & 1 & -1 & \color{red}{2b_1-b_2}\\
       0 & 0 & 0  & \color{red}{-3b_1+b_2+b_3}   
    \end{array}
   \right]$

Now, I want to get $\ker(\mathrm A)$

$\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 1  \\
   0 & 1 & -1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0    
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 x_1 \\
 x_2 \\
 x_3
 \end{pmatrix} = 0
 \implies 
 \begin{cases}
   x_1 + x_3 = 0 \implies x_1 = -x_3 \\
   x_2 - x_3 = 0 \implies x_2 = x_3
 \end{cases}
$

So, replacing in $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)=(-x_3,x_3,x_3)=x_3(-1,1,1) \implies \ker(\mathrm A) = \mathrm{gen}[(-1,1,1)]$

Now I want to get $\mathrm C(A)$

$\mathrm{C(A)=gen}[(1,2,1),(1,1,-1),(0,1,2)] \iff \color{red}{-3b_1+x_2+x_3=0} \implies \mathrm{C(A)=\{x \in \Bbb R^n : -2x_1+x_2+x_3=0\}}$

Then with $x=(-2,1,1), \mathrm{C(A)=\ker(X)}$

This is only one example to clarify my doubt.

So, finally, my question is:

Can be $\mathrm C(A)$ written as above? If the question is positive, can you give prove or give me an approximate idea of this?

Thanks for advance!

PS: if the example is wrong, please let me know.

Comment: What is $X$ in your example?

Answer (score 0):

You may not find this satisfying, but given that the image of $A$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, a matrix $B$ will vanish on the image of $A$ just if its row vectors are each perpendicular to each column vector of $A$. If you want a matrix to vanish only there, then you can find a basis for the orthogonal complement of the image of $A$, which will consist of $k = n - \textrm{rank}(A)$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and create a $k \times n$ matrix $B$ from these rows.